# Вложеные циклы for в Javascript

Tags: javascript, циклы

Люди помогите!

```
for (var i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < myFamily.length; j++) {
        document.write(myFamily[i][j] + " ");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

нужно что бы во внутреннем цикле вывод не делался, а только накапливалась строка а вывод строки делался во внешнем цикле. Помогите, что нужно делать? Зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Нужно ввести переменную, а потом уже выводить её:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++) {
    var str = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < myFamily.length; j++) {
        str += myFamily[i][j] + " ";
    }
    document.write(str + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: потенциальный выход за границы массива, а точнее 100%-ный. тут обход двумерного (?) массива два раза по длине.

Comment: `for (var j = 0; j < myFamily[i].length; j++) {`